# Cordova emulate on current emulator window. Not new window

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

When I'm using `cordova emulate`, most of times cordova starts new emulator window and I have to wait for the emulator to boot up everytime.

How can I tell cordova to emulate on currently opened emulator window?

I'm using Cordova 5, AVD running android 4.4.2 and 2.3.3

Answer (score 1):

Emulate in currently opened emulator:
`cordova emulate --target=emulator-5554 android`

you can check emulator name in :
`/platforms/android/cordova/lib/list-started-emulators.bat`

*or*

**Check on opened emulator window**